# Swapping elements inside linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a linked list that consist of nodes of

```
struct Node{
    Node(string k , string v , Node * n){
        key = k;
        val = v;
        next_hash = n;
    }
    string key;
    string val;
    Node *next_hash = NULL;
    Node *next_node = NULL;
    Node *prev_node = NULL;
};
```

I am creating double linked list ( next_hash will stay NULL for this example );

I have created a method to add a node to it using.

```
void add(string k , string v){
    Node *tmp = new Node( k , v , NULL);
    if( first == NULL ){
        first = tmp;
        last  = tmp;
    }else{
        last -> next_node = tmp;
        tmp  -> prev_node = last;
        last              = tmp;
    }
}
```

and i want to create a method that swaps Nodes. I created

```
 void swap( string k , string l){
        size_t klucik = hashfn(k);
        size_t kluc   = hashfn(l);

        Node *one = first;
        Node *two = first;
        while( one ){
            if( one -> key == k ){
                break;
            }

            one = one -> next_hash;
        }
        while ( two ){
            if( two -> key == l ){
                break;
            }

            two  = two -> next_hash;
        }

        Node *two_temp = two -> prev_node;
        Node *two_tmp = two -> next_node;

        if( one -> prev_node){
            one -> prev_node -> next_node = two;
            two -> prev_node = one -> prev_node;
        }
        else{
            first = two;
            two -> prev_node = NULL;
        }
        if( one -> next_node){
            one -> next_node -> prev_node = two;
            two -> next_node = one -> next_node;
        }else{
            two -> next_node = NULL;
            last = one;
        }
        if( two_temp ){
            two_temp -> next_node = one;
            one -> prev_node = two_temp;
        }
        else{
            first = one;
            one -> prev_node = NULL;
        }
        if( two_tmp ){
            two_tmp-> prev_node = one;
            one -> next_node = two_tmp;
        }
        else{
            last = one;
            one -> next_node = NULL;
        }

    }
```

this method works if i sam swapping Nodes that arent next to others.
If i do , it throws infnte loop of node that points to itself.

Is there any elegant way of creating universal swap method that counts with all possible location of nodes in linked list without tons of if condition?

I have tried , as comment suggested first swap Nodes and then pointers inside nodes using
    void swap( string k , string l){

```
    Node *one = first;
    Node *two = first;
    while( one ){
        if( one -> key == k ){
            break;
        }
        one = one -> next_node;
    }
    while ( two ){
        if( two -> key == l ){
            break;
        }
        two  = two -> next_node;
    }

    Node *two_temp = two -> prev_node;
    Node *two_tmp = two -> next_node;

    if( one -> prev_node)
        one -> prev_node -> next_node = two;
    else
        first = two;

    if( one -> next_node)
        one -> next_node -> prev_node = two;
    else
        last = two;

    if( two -> prev_node )
        two -> prev_node -> next_node = one;
    else
        first = one;

    if( two -> next_node )
        two -> next_node -> prev_node = one;
    else
        last = one;

    if( one -> next_node == two ){
        two -> next_node = one;
        two -> prev_node = one -> prev_node;
        one -> next_node = two_tmp;
        one -> prev_node = two_temp;
    }
    else if(one -> prev_node == two ){
            two -> next_node = one -> next_node;
            two -> prev_node = one;
            one -> next_node = two;
            one -> prev_node = two_temp;
    }
    else{
        two -> next_node = one -> next_node;
        two -> prev_node = one -> prev_node;
        one -> next_node = two_tmp;
        one -> prev_node = two_temp;
    }
}
```

Using this and test data

```
one.add("one","1");
one.add("two","2");
one.add("three","3");
one.add("four","4");
one.swap("one","two");
one.print(); // outputs 2 1 3 4
cout << " ============ " << endl;
one.swap("three","two");
one.print(); // outputs 2 4
```

I seem to fail find the right way of swapping nodes.

Comment: To deal with both separated and adjacent node swaps, first swap whatever points to the nodes (other nodes, head, tail, ...), then swap the pointers within the nodes.

Comment: @rcgldr  I have tried this but the result threw wrong output. I updated my answer for the code i used.

Comment: Take the case of swapping the first and last nodes. Step 1: swap first and last. Step 2: swap the two nodes next_node and prev_node. I'm not sure what next_hash is being used for.

Comment: @rcgldr I tried to implement as i uptated the answer of my attempt , it still fails tho , would you mind showing example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pointers to pointers will simplify the logic and they won't change during a swap of (*p... ,  *p... ). The contents (pointers to nodes) are swapped, but not the pointers to pointers.

```
Node **pnpone;   // ptr to next ptr to one
Node **pppone;   // ptr to prev ptr to one
Node **pnptwo;   // ptr to next ptr to two
Node **ppptwo;   // ptr to prev ptr to two
// ...
    if(one->prev_node)
        pnpone = &(one->prev_node->next_node);
    else
        pnpone = &first;
    if(one->next_node)
        pppone = &(one->next_node->prev_node);
    else
        pppone = &last;
    if(two->prev_node)
        pnptwo = &(two->prev_node->next_node);
    else
        pnptwo = &first;
    if(two->next_node)
        ppptwo = &(two->next_node->prev_node);
    else
        ppptwo = &last;
    std::swap(*pnpone, *pnptwo);
    std::swap(*pppone, *ppptwo);
    std::swap(one->prev_node, two->prev_node);
    std::swap(one->next_node, two->next_node);
```

Comment: I have quite hard time understand this. Lets say we have 4 nodes like in example , 1 2 3 4 , and i want to swap 1 and 3. 
pnpone would point to the memory in pc where first is located;
pppone would point to the memory in pc where one is located (the same as pnpone hre )
pnptwo would point to the memory in pc where three is located;
ppptwo would point to the memory in pc where three is located;
Using swap   std::swap(*pnpone, *pnptwo);
    std::swap(*pppone, *ppptwo); i would swap the memory in pc that points to these two so first points to three and three to one? Could you pls elaborate?

Comment: @Josh - pnpone would be the address of first and pppone would be the address of 2->prev_node, both containing pointers to 1. pnptwo would be the address of 2->next_node and ppptwo would be the address of 4->prev_node, both containing pointers to 3. std::swap(*pnpone, *pnptwo) ends up with first pointing to 3, and 2->next node pointing to 1. std::swap(*pppone, *ppptwo) ends up with 2->prev_node pointing to 3, and 4->prev_node pointing to 1. Then the node pointers are swapped. The end result going forwards is first->3->2->1->4->null, and going backwards, last->4->1->2->3->null.

Comment: @Josh - the reason for doing this is to save the addresses of the pointers to be swapped before doing the swaps, so that swapping the pointers doesn't affect the saved addresses. This allows the same logic to be used for adjacent or non-adjacent nodes.